# Why is my y variable stopping at 6?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on making a program that will take a form response, compare one cell in the column (such as the topic), and paste it in the appropriate row in another sheet. I've been working on it for a few weeks now, but seem to be getting stuck due to a couple issues.

```js
function checkForDuplicate() {
  //Sets 'data' as the variable holding values from the first sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("responses");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Sets 'data2' as the variable holding values from the second sheet.
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var data2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Sets a variable for the numerical length of data
  var responsesLength = data.length;
  var x = 1;
  var y = 0;
  //Finds a value that is the same as one in the second sheet.
  while (true) {
    var input = data[responsesLength - 1][0];
    var output = data2[y][0]
    Logger.log(input);
    Logger.log(output);
    if (input == output) {
      var rowLength = data[responsesLength - 1].length;
      for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
        copyData("responses", x, responsesLength, "Form Responses 2", x, 5);
        x = x + 1
        break;
      }
    } else {
      y = y + 1;
      Logger.log(y);
      if (y >= 10) {
        Logger.log("Error. No same value found.");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One of the major problems affecting my own troubleshooting is that my "y" variable will not count past 6. The Log will continue to log the value of y, but as soon as it reaches 6, it will stop logging, and y will not count up as the program does not end. I was wondering if anyone knew a fix to this?

Here are the Logs given by the Logger

1. [18-05-03 10:20:55:327 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC
2. [18-05-03 10:20:55:328 PDT] Timestamp
3. [18-05-03 10:20:55:329 PDT] 1.0
4. [18-05-03 10:20:55:329 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC
5. [18-05-03 10:20:55:330 PDT] Tue Apr 24 13:11:11 GMT-04:00 2018
6. [18-05-03 10:20:55:330 PDT] 2.0
7. [18-05-03 10:20:55:331 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC
8. [18-05-03 10:20:55:331 PDT] Thu May 03 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018
9. [18-05-03 10:20:55:332 PDT] 3.0
10. [18-05-03 10:20:55:333 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC
11. [18-05-03 10:20:55:333 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XL
12. [18-05-03 10:20:55:334 PDT] 4.0
13. [18-05-03 10:20:55:334 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC
14. [18-05-03 10:20:55:335 PDT] Cotton Sweatshirt XLC

Cotton Sweatshirt XLC will continue infinitely until I kill the program.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZZTWTTkdAESBWhHhpurcDMtohfIlVvt9z5x9wc2GKQ8/edit?usp=sharing

This is a test document I've been using to create this code. There's no sensitive data inside it, meaning it's free for me to share for purposes of fixing the problems I'm having.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the content of `data` and `data2`?

Comment: There isn't enough details to help you debug your code. Please checkout [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because for y = 7 it found a match. In the block for `input == output` you forgot to increment `y`!